# What is minus a in a spf record

Tags: dns, spf

I have a client that have a spf record i don't understand.
The record is like this:

```
"v=spf1 a:domain.tld -a:gmail.com -a:googlemail.com -ip4:xx1.yy1.zz1.xx -ip4:xx2.yy2.zz2.xx include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:servers.mcsv.net ?all"
```

I have changed the ip's to x y and z, but it is real ips and the domain i also real and not domain.tld.

What does the minus in -a: and -ip4: do? does it have a function or is it wrongly setup? 
I would like to clean up - can I just remove them? They use mailchimp, so I will just keep the 2 includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant bits of the RFC are [4.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.6.2) and [5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.3). Roughly

- `-` means 'fail', i.e. reject any sender that matches this rule
- `a:` means 'all IP addresses that this hostname resolves to'

So the intention of the rule appears to be to prevent anyone using gmail to send email from this domain, presumably because they used Google G-Suite for email at one time but have then stopped.

However I don't think that will work: [Google's SPF configuration](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786) is more complicated than that and uses 'include:' to pick up lists of addresses specified by Google. I'd be surprised if all of their mailservers hosted the gmail web app too. So my guess would be that this doesn't actually work as-is, and so can be safely deleted.

Ditto the `-ipv4` means don't allow this IP address to send email for your customer's domain. Chances are that's OK to go too, but you should verify what the IP address represents e.g. starting with a WHOIS lookup to see who (or which ISP) it's registered to.